# What am I not seeing whilst getting info from a String[]

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to split up my info first into a String[] by using "\n" as delimiter and than afterwards ,split them again into a String[] but this time using ";" as delimiter.
I however fail at getting info out of the second split.

```
    public static void initHashMap(){
    String[] lijnen = readDefinitioncsv(definitioncsv).split("\n");
    for (int i =2;i<lijnen.length;i++){
        String[] detaillijn = lijnen[i].split(";");



        // on the line below I get 
        //java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

        int rood = Integer.parseInt(detaillijn[1]);
        int groen = Integer.parseInt(detaillijn[2]);
        int blauw = Integer.parseInt(detaillijn[3]);
        String provincieNaam = detaillijn[4];
        RGBProvince.put(new Color(rood,groen,blauw), provincieNaam);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: how many "\n" do you have?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of a `definitioncsv` file you are reading from? If the csv has less than 3 `";"`s it won't work.

Comment: Some debugging, or at least a simple `System.out.println("Splitting \""+lijnen[i]+"\" gives "+Arrays.toString(detaillijn));` might already bring some insights here...

Comment: " I however fail at getting info out of the second split." What do you mean by this? What input are you giving the function? What does the input file look like? What happens when you run your program? Does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] lijnen = readDefinitioncsv(definitioncsv).split("\r?\n");
for (int i =2;i<lijnen.length;i++){
    String[] detaillijn = lijnen[i].split("[,;\t]");
    if (detaillijn.length < 5) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Weiniger als 5 elementen: "
                + lijnen[i]);
    }
```

This handles Windows line endings (`\r\n` aka CR+LF) and also other forms of CSV - as `;` did not seem to function.

May the file ends with an empty line, in which case you need to skip that with a `continue`.

For good order, indices start at 0; you seem to be skipping 2 header lines, and the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your for loop initializing at the third position?

```
for (int i =2;i<lijnen.length;i++){
```

presumably you want `i=0`?

also you array might not have 2 elements:

```
int rood = Integer.parseInt(detaillijn[1]);
```

this is the second position.  but it might have nothing because of the loop above.

You should probably check you have at least those many lines / columns before you hop straight to one in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing `i` to 2 in your `for` loop. If your `array` has less than three items, you will get an index out of bounds trying to access a location that does not exist.

Why not start with `int i = 0`?